# Why are rangeproofs necessary?

Tags: ringct, confidential-transactions, range-proofs

Title. This is probably a remarkably stupid question, but I digress. Now, I understand the point of rangeproofs, but I don't understand why they're actually necessary.

So, rangeproofs prevent a malicious user from committing to a negative number in the Pedersen Commitment. But going by that protocol ([example implementation](https://gitlab.kingston.ac.uk/K1531112/Pedersen-Commitment/tree/master)), successfully committing to a negative number should be impossible (or at least unreasonably expensive) if you choose a prime for g. Roots (which is what a negative exponent is) of any prime number are always going to be irrational, which means that you can't convert them back into an integer unless you multiply by g<sup>-n</sup> which brings them back to 1. Unless g<sup>2</sup> < q (which can be prevented by simply choosing a g which doesn't fit that rule), then it's barely even possible to commit to -1 because mod q only allows for 1 valid number, let alone anything higher which requires exponentially higher numbers to reach a valid integer. This means that you can simply reject any commitment that equals 1.

Not only that, but the discrete logarithm problem should mean that the chances of successfully getting 1 at all are essentially non-existent in the first place.

So, in short, I don't understand why rangeproofs are necessary. By my understanding, the commitment system in and of itself should be resistant against committing to negative numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you [cite](https://gitlab.kingston.ac.uk/K1531112/Pedersen-Commitment/tree/master) *is not* using elliptic curve operations.

A Pedersen commitment in Monero takes the form `C = xG + aH` (alternatively notated *C = g<sup>x</sup> ⋅ h<sup>a</sup>*) and here `G` and `H` (or *g* and *h*) are *elliptic curve points*, hence the operation is repeated addition (or subtraction) of the respective point. Thus `a` (or `x`) can indeed be a negative. So `-3H` (or h<sup>-3</sup>) translates as "subtract the point `H` from itself 3 times (i.e. `H - H - H - H`)".

With this understanding, it is indeed possible to commit to a value that is negative, and thus a range proof is needed to ensure the committed value is in the range `[0..2^64-1]`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I didn't know that Monero doesn't use the traditional scheme. That does bring up another question for me though, what's the reasoning for using the EC variant? I know that Monero of course makes use of ECC in other areas, but is there some benefit of using it here?

Comment: "I didn't know that Monero doesn't use the traditional scheme" <- Monero does use the "traditional scheme". Confidential Transactions uses ECC, and thus the values used in the Pedersen commitments are scalars and elliptic curve points.

Comment: Well okay, but then why does CT use ECC?

Comment: Why does anything use ECC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography#Rationale